# HTTP 400 Bad Request running python code from Text analytics in Azure Machine learning

Tags: python, azure

When running the Python code for Topic Detection (https://text-analytics-demo.azurewebsites.net/Home/SampleCode) I get a HTTP 400, Bad request.
I pasted my Azure key correctly and made a txt file with at least 100 documents.
The webservice is located at https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/topics.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is there a way to get more details on the error from the API?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description & my tesing, I think the issue was caused by the input file format that must match the JSON format shown in the first step of the section `Task 3` of the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cognitive-services-text-analytics-quick-start/#task-3---detect-topics-in-a-corpus-of-text). Please inspect the data format of your input file, then try again the sample code.

Comment: I get an 401 access Denied on the part in the while loop:  req = urllib2.Request(uri, None, headers).
But it seems the demo code URL is down for the moment?

Comment: @TJA According to the document https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn913081.aspx, the 401 status code means the request is unauthorized. Please refer to the article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-connect-to-azure-machine-learning-web-service/#get-an-azure-machine-learning-authorization-key to get the `apikey` for the header `Authorization` of the request. Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: The weird thing is that the first call passes correctly, but in the polling loop it stops at the first exec of req = urllib2.Request(uri, None, headers). My key is ok. I tried with both of them.